# EF Core 7: Update seeded data on every migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this simple class

```
public class TestModel: Entity //Entity has Id column
{
    public long Order_Id { get; private set; }
    public int Amount { get; private set; }

    public TestModel(long order_Id, int amount)
    {
        Order_Id = order_Id;
        Amount = amount;
    }
}
```

And my seed data looks like this:

```cs
\\ other configurations
builder.Property(b => b.Order_Id).HasColumnName("Order_Id")
builder.HasData(new { Id = 1L, Order_Id = 1L, Amount = 20});
```

Every time I add a migration without changing anything (after the initial migration where the data seeded successfully), it has an `UpdateData` call for the field `Order_Id`

```
public partial class test : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            schema: "db",
            table: "Test_Model",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: 1L,
            column: "Order_Id",
            value: 1L);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            schema: "db",
            table: "Test_Model",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: 1L,
            column: "Order_Id",
            value: 0L);
    }
}
```

The issue is solved when I rename `Order_Id` to `OrderId` (I know that camel case is the standard, and it was written in snake case by accident the first time).

But I'm here to ask what is the relation between the name convention in the model and the reseeding in the migration.

Any idea why this behavior happens?

Comment: what is the `OrderId ` name in the database table?

Comment: It's `Order_Id` in the database table, with this configuration `builder.Property(b => b.OrderId).HasColumnName("Order_Id")`

Comment: Now I am confused. From your previous comment, if you have `builder.Property(b => b.OrderId).HasColumnName("Order_Id")`, then the class is not what you have shown here. Which means you need to update the question in order to make it reproducible - please include the class with proper property names, data annotations if any and fluent configuration.

Comment: you're right, the current configuration is as I mentioned in the previous comment but before solving the issue it was `builder.Property(b => b.Order_Id).HasColumnName("Order_Id")`, I know this was a useless configuration but it was written by accident as I said, I have updated the question.

Comment: I think the error is due to the "private set".

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce. Clean net7.0 console project, EF Core 7.0.9 (SqlServer), adding the class, adding migration, adding second migration - it is empty. The strange thing in your example is the `value: 0L)` in the `Down` method. Not sure what could be causing it, is there something else not show here? The column sounds like FK, may be adding `Order` class and FK relationship configuration? In general, try to reproduce in a clean project, what you are getting is not a normal behavior, so either you are hitting some EFC bug, or there is something else in your code causing it.

Comment: @jdweng, I think if the error is due to the "private set", the migration would have the same behavior after renaming the property, but it is not

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't have any relationship configuration, do you add any seeding while reproducing the issue? the issue happens only when there are seeded data

Comment: I've added the code (`HasData`) from the question.

Comment: Do you mean the call shouldn't happen when migration?

Comment: @QiangFu Yes, the migration should be empty as long as I didn't change the seeded data

Comment: I also cannot reproduce in net6, add-migration twice just get empty up&down.